# How Can I Look Through A String in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to look through a very long string in Python and I am looking for the value that is in

```
<p class="price">$VALUE USD</p>
```

I am currently doing

```
look = "<p class=\"price\">";
print(site.text.find(look));
```

Because the  will always be there but I am looking for the value of the rest of the line. The value is always changing too so it needs to be flexible. At the end I hope to be able to save something like

```
<p class="price">$2345.22</p>
```

to a string.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: The text you are looking for is HTML. If your "very long string" is all HTML, you should use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "<p class=\"price\">$2345.22</p>"
regex = re.compile("<p class=\"price\">\\$([.\\d]*)</p>")
print(regex.match(text).group(1)) # -> 2345.22
```

Comment: I don't have the rest of the <p> element so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup to easily get the text from within the tags.
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Another way to get the value will be to use the python split method consecutively

```
string = '<p class="price">$VALUE USD</p>'
new_string = string.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
```

Comment: I don't have the full <p> value only the <p class=\"price\"> part so this doesn't work

Comment: @qwessin you can try using beautiful soup then